# P for trend calculation in R on betas in linear regression

Tags: r, trend

I have a question about calculating a p for trend based on betas from linear regression. I have created some data using R:

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
var1 <- c(60,80,90,55,60,61,77,67,88,90)
var2 <- c(55,88,88,55,70,61,80,66,65,92)
var3 <- c(62,88,85,56,68,62,89,62,70,99)
outcome <- c(1,5,3,7,3,9,6,3,2,6)
dat <- data.frame(id, var1, var2, var3, outcome)
dat

mod1 <- lm(outcome ~ var1, data = dat)
summary(mod1)           
# Beta =  -0.03100

mod2 <- lm(outcome ~ var2, data = dat)
summary(mod2)     
# Beta =  0.01304

mod3 <- lm(outcome ~ var3, data = dat)
summary(mod3) 
# Beta =  0.01544
```

So based on the betas, it looks like there is some kind of trend. I know I can check this by calculating a p for trend.
However, I am very new to statistics and I do not know how to calculate this p for trend. Can somebody help me by giving me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `summary` on a `lm` fitted model, the output should normally include p-values for the predictors of the model.

For example, when I run the command `summary(mod1)` I get the following output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = outcome ~ var1, data = dat)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.8968 -1.8426 -0.1218  1.8687  4.1342 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  6.75690    4.68435   1.442    0.187
var1        -0.03100    0.06333  -0.490    0.638

Residual standard error: 2.619 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.02908,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.09228 
F-statistic: 0.2396 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.6376
```

So in the rightmost column (`Pr(>|t|)`) the p-values for each of the predictors is given (including the intercept). This shows that the estimate `var1` is actually not significantly different from 0, with `p=0.638` (and the same for `var2` and `var3`).

Comment: I get that, but that is not the p for trend right? I see a trend within the betas: the association first changes from negative to positive and then the positive association becomes stronger. So that looks like a trend to me. And that is what I want to test

Comment: OK, it seems I misunderstood your question. But if you want to investigate a trend between the estimates of `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`, does that mean there is some relationship between them (eg, repeated measures)? In that case, you might need to re-code your data, such as a `var_id` and a `time` variable, but it's difficult to assess with the provided information. Note also that there is the sister website stats.stackexchange.com for statistical questions. You might want to try and ask your question there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, there is a relationship between them. They are repeated in time. I hope I explained it clear enough. But if you cannot help me further here, I will ask it there. Thank you for the tip!